# Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online Report layout

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, reportbuilder

I have to create an report in Microsoft CRM online.

Requirements:

1. Invoice(start on new page,1 page)
2. Optional Appendix A (start on new page, 1 or more pages)
3. Optional Appendix B (start on new page, 1 or more pages)

Everything I build, has not yet produced the desired result.

The Invoice report only is no problem, but when I include both Appendix A and B to the report, the print layout goes wrong. Page breaks are not included. Layout is shifted, etc, etc.

The Invoice is build in the main Tablix groupedby InvoiceID.
The Appendix A and B are build in a separate Tablix and are included in the main table in a row.

Does anyone have suggestions how this can be solved?

Thank you!